# d3.js load only parts of data / Synchronize data

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have very much data, which I draw as stacked Bars. My Testdata here is around 500k JSON-Objects (=50k lines with 10 stacked segments) big.

My problem is that I don´t knew how to load only parts of the data. It´s shown in an browser and so the width is around 1200 to 1920 pixels.
I am using an scale to calculate the Lines size. But if I set an tinier value to the window width than the size of the data, d3.js calculates the width for every Line to be 0, which means that nothing is shown. 
So, I have to set an width of 50k to show everything, but this is a little bit unpracticable - and it let´s the browser crash, it´s only working when I use around 10k of the data and then set an width of 10k px. And the 2nd thing is that it reallllly takes very long (5secs) to render.

1.) How am I able to take that data and show it in an window of width=1920 and - if I am moving the Arrow keys or an overview chart - load the other data?

2.) How is it possible to synchronize data? Eg.: If I had an long slider, this slider should determine at which data I am interested. So, the range is from 0 to 50k then I am sliding it and are at ~4000. I want to jump in the Graph to that position.

```
   dataset = data;
    var stack = d3.layout.stack();
    stack(dataset);

    var x= d3.scale.ordinal()
            .domain(d3.range(dataset[0].length))
            .rangeRoundBands([0, w]);

    var y= d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0, 1])
            .range([0, h]);

    var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h);

    var groups = svg.selectAll("g")
                    .data(dataset)
                    .enter()
                    .append("g");

    var rects = groups.selectAll("rect")
                    .data(function (d) {
                        return d;
                    })
                    .enter()
                    .append("rect")
                    .attr("x", function (d, i) {
                        return x(i);
                    })
                    .attr("y", function (d) {
                        return y(d.y0 + d.y);
                    })
                    .attr("height", function (d) {
                        return h - y(d.y0);
                    })
                    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
                    .attr("fill", function (d, i) {
                        return color(i);
                    });
```

Comment: You need to implement this on the server side. You can't load only parts of a file with D3.

Comment: How do I do that?....

Comment: ....Does that mean I am only able to draw one data Series at time? I just can´t believe that everyone has so few data that it always fits into one page.

Comment: I'm referring to *loading* the data. You don't have to use all the data you load at once.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, How would then be an proper and fast way to load an bunch of data (~10k lines) and update the seeable data fast? Without redrawing all the time?

Comment: You'll have to take subsets of your data for drawing, see Mark's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method to subset the data.  This doesn't reduce the data *loaded*. But gives you a way to reduce the amount of bars you draw on the graph at once.

```
data = all_data.slice(start_index, end_index);
```

Then set the `start_index` and `end_index` based on what data you want to display.  You can add an event listener, for which the callback function changes the start and end indices.

```
var refresh(){
    data = all_data.splice(start_index, end_index)
    //your code to redraw the graph using updated indices goes here
}

d3.select("body")
    .on("keydown", function() {
        if(d3.event.keyCode == 37){
            //left key press
            start_index = start_index - 4000;
            end_index = end_index-4000;
            if (start_index < 0){
                //handle boundary case
                start_index = 0;
                end_index = 4000;
            }
            refresh();
        }
        else if(d3.event.keyCode == 39){
            //right key press
            start_index = start_index + 4000;
            end_index = end_index + 4000;
            if (end_index > all_data.length){
                start_index = all_data.length-4000;
                end_index = all_data.length;
            }
            refresh();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. Since I have an 2D-Array of JSON Objects I would have to make an own splice for that. But with that everything is redrawn, at an "update" ?

Comment: You would change the domain and redraw the bars in `refresh()`.  There may be some parts of the svg you don't need to update in refresh (eg titles, axis lines).

Comment: When I am updating that stuff. And only add change the data from (0 to 300) to (1 to 301), will d3 keep the 299 existing svg´s or calculate and repaint them again?

Comment: You can assign a key function to your data to achieve object constancy, which is important if you want to do animated transitions.  See http://bost.ocks.org/mike/constancy/