# Porting d3.js SVG to HTML5 Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, d3.js, svg

Two days ago I opened an question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32082321/d3-js-load-only-parts-of-data-synchronize-data)) to draw much Elements (50k) very fast with d3. With that I figured out that d3 is way too slow for my need and need something completely different or an other approach.

The data to be drawn is with Canvas around 15 times faster and I have seen [this](http://bl.ocks.org/syntagmatic/2409451). So, it seems that it´s possible to move d3 to Canvas. But I don´t get how to rewrite my Code for the use of Canvas.

```
 dataset = data;
var stack = d3.layout.stack();
stack(dataset);

var x= d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(d3.range(dataset[0].length))
        .rangeRoundBands([0, w]);

var y= d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, 1])
        .range([0, h]);

var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h);

var groups = svg.selectAll("g")
                .data(dataset)
                .enter()
                .append("g");

var rects = groups.selectAll("rect")
                .data(function (d) {
                    return d;
                })
                .enter()
                .append("rect")
                .attr("x", function (d, i) {
                    return x(i);
                })
                .attr("y", function (d) {
                    return y(d.y0 + d.y);
                })
                .attr("height", function (d) {
                    return h - y(d.y0);
                })
                .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
                .attr("fill", function (d, i) {
                    return color(i);
                });
```

How can I change that to Canvas Usage? Is there any Tutorial which describes how to do that? Or are other Libraries better for that usage?

Comment: There are canvas charting libraries that will draw barcharts based on JSON data, but a basic canvas barchart is remarkably simple to code. Here's a barchart in a function with less than 20 lines: https://jsfiddle.net/mgpLghcy/

Comment: Elijah Meeks' book *D3.js in Action* is a pretty good source on this topic.  The Canvas material is in one of the later chapters.

Answer (score 0):

here is a nice example using Canvas drawing with D3 to show overlay on top of Open Layers map. For large number of objects Canvas shows better performance compared to SVG. Tested with 500000 lines

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/d3.html